# What is the limit on the number of "fast", "inlinable" properties in v8 object?

Tags: javascript, caching, limit, inline, v8

Question for v8 experts.

As we know, if the "shape" of the object does not change, v8 stores the object properties in a special array, and access them by index, which results in very fast access. I may be wrong on the details.

As described in [this blog post](https://v8.dev/blog/hash-code) from 2018, the size limit for this array is 1022.

Is this information still correct? Perhaps there were some improvements on this recently?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need to improve that number? No reasonable object has that many properties. For anything larger, you'd use a `Map` anyway.

Comment: @Bergi: "improvement" does not imply a direction, it could mean raising or lowering the value ;-)

Comment: @Bergi My goal is to implement better v8 polymorphism in user-space: https://github.com/canonic-epicure/monopoly

I'm making small experiments about how that can be done, one of them stores the v-tables as objects. Thing is v8 is implemented in such way, that a v-table for certain mixin need to contain _all_ properties of classes this mixin is involved in. Thus the need for big objects. And I want access to v-table entries to be fast of course.

Comment: Under "improvement" I mean increasing the limit of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know how that blog post arrived at that number, the current value of `kMaxNumberOfDescriptors` is 1020, and the maximum number of entries in a `PropertiesArray` is 1023. Not sure why there's a difference, also not sure it matters... In a quick test, it seems that 1020 is the effective maximum, but maybe I'm overlooking some way to make an object grow to 1022 properties without transitioning to dictionary mode.

Meta-observation: object handling in a JS engine is waaaay more complicated than just having a single limit. See e.g. [TooManyFastProperties()](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/objects/map-inl.h;l=181?q=TooManyFastProperties&sq=) for some of the fun.

> if the "shape" of the object does not change, v8 stores the object properties in a special array

This is an incorrect simplification. In particular, adding properties (which constitutes a shape change) does not usually trigger a transition to dictionary mode.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Of course the difference between 1020 and 1022 is not significant. What about `TooManyFastProperties()` btw? It says something about constant function properties not counted as regular ones?

Comment: Yes; looks like it triggers transitions to dictionary mode earlier in some circumstances.